# Google Workspace Marketplace addon present in Gmail Web and Android but missing in Gmail iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

We have developed a Google Workspace Addon which uses **Alternate Runtimes**. It works fine on the WEB and ANDROID platforms, but **not on iOS**. No addon icon is present at the bottom when opening an email in the Gmail iOS app.

To clarify, the addon is entirely missing from the account, so there might be an interpretation issue with the manifest file. No logging is being created in Cloud Console's Logs Explorer, so no details there.

Opened a support ticket with Google which escalated it to the engineering team and they said:

"*We received an update today and we have been able to reproduce this scenario on our end  and it seems the problem is related to the add on and not the way it was deployed to Marketplace.
In this case since the issue is related to the Add on deployment we will not be able to further investigate on our end but if you believe it is related to a bug on our end you can submit a bug by accessing the following link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support#bug or you can also visit Stack Overflow as we have hundreds of developers and Google engineers that can provide you some insight about the issue that you are experiencing.*"

What is wrong with this deployment? I thought the Workspace addons were unified across all platforms. Manifest file below.

```
{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "***",
      "logoUrl": "***",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "universalActions": [{
        "label": "My Emails",
        "openLink": "***"
      }, {
        "label": "Frequently Asked Questions",
        "openLink": "***"
      }, {
        "label": "Mobile Help",
        "openLink": "***"
      }, {
        "label": "Contact us",
        "openLink": "***"
      }, {
        "label": "My Account",
        "openLink": "***"
      }]
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [{
        "unconditional": {
        },
        "onTriggerFunction": "redacted"
      }],
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [{
          "text": "redacted",
          "runFunction": "redacted"
        }],
        "draftAccess": "METADATA"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "redacted"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Android vs iOS]

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to use an alternate runtime. Have you learned anything more since? Support is writing me off telling me it's my bug and I should check SO. If its our bug, something is clearly missing from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else down the rabbit hole I've been down in the last few hours.
The Google Workspace instructions on [Set up an Apple push certificate](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F6080359%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_event=welcome&assistant_id=mdmbot&product_context=6080359&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a) might have helped.
However I still couldn't get the add-on to appear deploying as an alternative runtime from Node JS. Instead I refactored the UI in App Scripts and [just fetched data that required more work from a server hosted on Cloud Run](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-call-google-cloud-run-or-cloud-functions-from-apps-scripts-c0086289c965).